# Symbol not found: _mpfr_acos, Expected in: flat namespace

Tags: python, mpfr, bigfloat

I am trying to run a Python script that includes multiple packages. The error I continuously get involves the mpfr.so file (MPFR module). Here are the contents of the entire message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rebekahgruver/Desktop/solver/spopt-stable/SpOpt.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bigfloat import BigFloat
  File "/Users/rebekahgruver/Desktop/macPKG/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bigfloat/__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from bigfloat.core import (
  File "/Users/rebekahgruver/Desktop/macPKG/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bigfloat/core.py", line 26, in <module>
    import mpfr
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/rebekahgruver/Desktop/macPKG/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpfr.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mpfr_acos
  Referenced from: /Users/rebekahgruver/Desktop/macPKG/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpfr.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I have gone in circles trying to reinstall the packages and haven't been able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need missing libraries MPFR and possibly GMP.
If you have homebrew installed on your system, try:

```
brew install gmp
brew install mpfr
```

> In order to use the bigfloat package you will need to have both the
>   GMP and MPFR libraries already installed on your system, along with
>   the include files for those libraries. See the MPFR homepage and the
>   GMP homepage for more information about these libraries. Currently,
>   MPFR version 2.3.0 or later is required.

Source: http://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/#prerequisites

Comment: Yes I have already installed both through homebrew. Which is why I am unsure it is even giving me that error?